# How to keep values in the form for php file upload

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to keep file upload value in the form after submission.

I've tried adding the upload file as value, using $_SESSION. I have no trouble keeping the values of other inputs in the form after submission, just not file upload.

```
<form id = '##' action='##.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Upload logo:<br>
        <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' class = 'file' id='fileToUpload' value="<?PHP echo $_SESSION['##']; ?>">


<label>###</label>
    <div class = 'input'><input type = 'text'  id = '###' name = '###' value = "<?PHP echo $_SESSION['###']; ?>" placeholder=" ex: #####"></div><br>


<input type="submit" id = 'submit' name="submit">
```

My expected result was that it should keep the file upload value in the form after submission to save re-submitting the file. The actual result was the file upload was not saved in the form after submission

Comment: This won't work because it points to an explicit choice by the user relating to a file on their machine. You don't have the permission clearance to retain a link to that file after a page transition. The best you can do is to AJAX the form, rather than having a page transition via a normal submission.

Comment: thanks for your answer